# NSAnimationContext crashing when called by an Observer

Tags: swift, macos, core-graphics, core-animation, nsanimationcontext

I have two WebViews: `webView` and `customizerWebView`. Both of these WKWebViews are attached by a trailing constraint. Essentially, when I go to the menu and click "Show Customizer" `showCustomizer()` or "Hide Customizer" `hideCustomizer()`, it calls the respective function and either shows or hides all the things related to `customizerWebView`.

To clarify, everything works and animates as expected when calling these functions from their attached `NSMenuItems`. *However,* when `show/hideCustomizer()` gets called from an Observer that essentially detects a URL - ie. `url.contains("#close")` - the app crashes on the first line of `animator()` code with the error: `Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value`

**ViewController.swift**

```
import Cocoa
import WebKit

class ViewController: NSViewController, WKUIDelegate, WKNavigationDelegate {
    var customizerURLObserver: NSKeyValueObservation?

    @IBOutlet var webView: WKWebView!
    @IBOutlet var customizerWebView: WKWebView!
    @IBOutlet var rightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad
        ...
        customizerURLObserver = customizerWebView.observe(\.url, options: .new) { webView, change in
            let url = "\(String(describing: change.newValue))"
            ViewController().urlDidChange(urlString: url) }
    }

    func urlDidChange(urlString: String) {
        let url = cleanURL(urlString)
        if url.contains("#close") { hideCustomizer() }  // Observer call to hide function
    }

    @IBAction func showCustomizerMenu(_ sender: Any) { showCustomizer() }  // These work flawlessly
    @IBAction func hideCustomizerMenu(_ sender: Any) { hideCustomizer() }  // These work flawlessly

    func showCustomizer() {
        let customTimeFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(controlPoints: 5/6, 0.2, 2/6, 0.9)
        NSAnimationContext.runAnimationGroup({(_ context: NSAnimationContext) -> Void in
            context.timingFunction = customTimeFunction
            context.duration = 0.3
            rightConstraint.animator().constant = 280
            customizerWebView.animator().isHidden = false
            webView.animator().alphaValue = 0.6
        }, completionHandler: {() -> Void in
        })
    }

    func hideCustomizer() {
        let customTimeFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(controlPoints: 5/6, 0.2, 2/6, 0.9)
        NSAnimationContext.runAnimationGroup({(_ context: NSAnimationContext) -> Void in
            context.timingFunction = customTimeFunction
            context.duration = 0.3
            webView.animator().alphaValue = 1     // Found nil crash highlights this line
            rightConstraint.animator().constant = 0
        }, completionHandler: {() -> Void in
            self.customizerWebView.isHidden = true
        })
    }
}
```

Could someone please enlighten me as to why this animation looks and works flawlessly 100 times when called from the NSMenu, but crashes when `hideCustomizer()` gets called once from an Observer function?

I have also tried calling the NSMenu object function `hideCustomizerMenu(self)`, but to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the line:

```swift
ViewController().urlDidChange(urlString: url)
```

you are mistakenly creating a new instance of your view controller class and calling `urlDidChange` on *that* instance. Since this new instance is not created from a storyboard/xib, all of its outlets are nil, and thus when you try to call the `animator` method on its `webView` in `hideCustomizer`, it crashes because it's nil.

Instead, call `urlDidChange` on `self` (actually a weakified `self` so that you don't create a retain cycle):

```swift
customizerURLObserver = customizerWebView.observe(\.url, options: .new) { [weak self] webView, change in
    let url = "\(String(describing: change.newValue))"
    self?.urlDidChange(urlString: url)
}
```

Comment: Now I feel foolish. Thank you very much – for both the corrected code **and** explanation! Now I know not to make the same mistake in the future. Just a quick followup if you have the time: Why choose a `weak self` in instances like these? How would I go about knowing when to choose a `weak self` upon coding a new project or function?

Comment: No prob! In this particular case, I knew to use `[weak self]` because `self` owns a strong reference to `customizerURLObserver`, which owns a strong reference to the change handler closure specified in the call to `observe(_:options:)`, which would own a strong reference to `self` if I had not made `self` weak – so there would have been a retain cycle going from self->customizerURLObserver->closure->self, which would create a memory leak because none of those things would ever deallocate. In general, though, you pretty much just have to be aware of what holds strong references to what.